# Quando utilizar prototype (JS)

Tags: javascript

Qual a diferença entre:

```
Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    alert("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName);
};
```

e

```
Person.sayHello = function() {
    alert("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName);
};
```

?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A diferença é melhor explicitada com um exemplo:

```
var Person = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.sayHello = function() {
  console.log("Hello " + this.name);
}

Person.prototype.sayHi = function() {
  console.log("Hi "+ this.name);
}

var p1 = new Person("Fulano");

Person.sayHello(); // "Hello "
p1.sayHello();     // Erro: sayHello não está definido
p1.sayHi();        // "Hi Fulano"
```

Quando você adiciona alguma função ou atributo ao prototype, esta função (ou atributo) fica disponível a todas as instâncias da classe (criadas com o `new`).

Quando você altera sem o prototype, somente o objeto em questão possui a função/atributo. As instâncias não o possuem.

Note que é possível definir os métodos diretamente dentro da sua classe, usando o `this`:

```
var Person = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.sayHi = function() {
    console.log("Hi " + this.name);
  }
}

var p1 = new Person("Fulano");
p1.sayHi();        // "Hi Fulano"
```

Como observado pelo @bfavaretto: "se você tiver várias instâncias do mesmo objeto, melhor colocar no prototype. Senão cada objeto terá sua própria cópia do método, geralmente é um desperdício de recursos".

Comment: No caso se eu definir os métodos dentro do objeto, não teria a necessidade de adicionar ao prototype, correto?

Comment: Se você criar os métodos com o `this`, não precisa.

Comment: Ahh certo, entendi, vlww!

Comment: Nota (sobre a última parte): se você tiver várias instâncias do mesmo objeto, melhor colocar no prototype. Senão cada objeto terá sua própria cópia do método, geralmente é um desperdício de recursos.

Comment: Certo, neste caso será apenas 1 instancia do objeto mesmo, pois fiz um objeto com todas as funcionalidades, é um pequeno site. Mas vlw pela dica!

Answer (score 13):

Ok, vamos a alguns pontos...

## São apenas três grandes casos

Tudo se resume a três grandes casos:

---

### 1: Função do protótipo

A seguinte situação ilustra a declaração de um protótipo, com uma função de protótipo:

```
var Person = function(firstName){
    if(!firstName) this.firstName = "Fulano";
    else this.firstName = firstName;
}
Person.prototype.sayHello = function(){ alert("Hi, I'm " + this.firstName); };
```

Qualquer objeto declarado a partir deste protótipo (`var a = new Person();`) terá acesso à função. Mesmo que realizássemos nossa instância antes da própria declaração da função, ainda assim ela passaria a ter acesso tão logo a função fosse declarada:

```
var Person = function(firstName){
    if(!firstName) this.firstName = "Fulano";
    else this.firstName = firstName;
}
var a = new Person();

// Neste trecho, 'a' ainda não conhece a função, e uma chamada resultaria
// em um erro de execução.

Person.prototype.sayHello = function(){ alert("Hi, I'm " + this.firstName); };

// Já neste trecho, 'a' já conhece a função e poderia chamá-la.
```

---

### 2: Função da instância

As instâncias do protótipo, sendo objetos, podem conter atributos e métodos. O que você acha que aquele `this` faz?

```
// ...
if(!firstName) this.firstName = "Fulano";
else this.firstName = firstName;
// ...
```

Cada instância, caso especifique um parâmetro `firstName` quando da chamada à função `Person`, receberá seu próprio atributo chamado... *`firstName`*!!! (Mas poderia ser outro nome, sem alterar o nome do parâmetro da função!)

```
var Person = function(firstName){
    if(!firstName) this.nome = "Fulano";
    else this.nome = firstName;
}
```

Em resumo: o `this` declarará, dentro do objeto (instância), um atributo **ou método** (como no exemplo abaixo):

```
var Person = function(firstName){
    if(!firstName) this.firstName = "Fulano";
    else this.firstName = firstName;
    this.sayHello = function(){ alert("Hi, I'm " + this.firstName);
}
```

Cada instância deste protótipo `Person` sai "de fábrica" com seu próprio atributo `firstName` e sua própria função `sayHello()`. Como muito bem apontado pelo @bfavaretto, isto pode significar um grande desperdício de recursos, pois mesmo idênticas, as funções de cada objeto são declaradas de maneira independente; é como se, por trás dos panos, cada instância do protótipo (`var a = new Person("Rui"); var b = new Person("Ricardo");`) fosse declarada de uma maneira parecida com essa:

```
var c = {};
c.firstName = "Rui";
c.sayHello = function(){ alert("Hi, I'm " + this.firstName);

var d = {};
d.firstName = "Ricardo";
d.sayHello = function(){ alert("Hi, I'm " + this.firstName);
```

Obviamente, uma diferença crucial do exemplo acima para a instanciação é que de forma alguma 'c' e 'd' podem ser considerados instâncias de `Person` (`c.constructor == "function Object() { [native code] }"`, enquanto que `a.constructor ==` *definição do protótipo `Person`*).

Porém, fica bastante evidente, neste ponto, que cada instância está "livre para seguir seu próprio caminho", criando definições alternativas para sua própria função (suas próprias `sayHello()` customizadas), e, assim, anulando em seu escopo a definição original.

Isto posto, vale ressaltar que podemos tirar proveito do melhor dos dois mundos: economizar recursos, ao mesmo tempo em que permitimos definições próprias para cada instância. E como isto é feito? Obtendo vantagem a partir do fato de que **as instâncias procuram, primeiro, atributos e métodos próprios** e, depois, os do protótipo:

```
var Person = function(firstName){
    if(!firstName) this.firstName = "Fulano";
    else this.firstName = firstName;
}
Person.prototype.sayHello = function(){ alert("Hi, I'm " + this.firstName); };
var a = new Person("Evandro");
var b = new Person("Fabrício");

// Neste trecho, 'a' e 'b' conhecem apenas a definição original da função 'sayHello()'; por sinal, as definições NÃO FORAM duplicadas para dentro de cada instância do protótipo!

a.sayHello = function(){ alert("Viva la revolucion!"); }

// 'b' procura primeiramente a função `sayHello()` dentro de si, mas não encontra e acaba executando a função do protótipo:
b.sayHello();

// Já 'a' procura a função dentro de si e **ENCONTRA**, motivo pelo qual ela executa sua própria definição "particular" ao invés da do protótipo:
a.sayHello();
```

---

### 3: Função da função (a.k.a. "Madness? This is JavaScript!")

Até aqui, apresentei soluções válidas para o que você quer fazer. Veja que não falei sobre a opção:

```
Person.sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Hello " + this.name);
}
```

Por mais incrível que possa parecer para o pessoal que está começando, no JavaScript as funções nada mais são do que instâncias do protótipo chamado... *Function*!!

```
var Person = function(){};
console.log(Person.constructor); // function Function() { [native code] }
```

Então... o que nos impede de declararmos uma função nesta nossa (instância de) função? **Na verdade, nada**:

```
var Person = function(firstName){
    if(!firstName) this.firstName = "Fulano";
    else this.firstName = firstName;
}
Person.sayHello = function() {
    alert("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName);
};
Person.sayHello(); // Hello, I'm undefined
Person.firstName = "Função";
Person.sayHello(); // Hello, I'm Função
```

---

## Conclusões

1. Utilize a declaração no protótipo (`Person.prototype.funcao = ...`) para disponibilizar a definição da função para todas as instâncias; o mesmo serve para atributos.
2. Você pode declarar definições particulares nas instâncias (`a.funcao = ...`), sempre que necessário.
3. Definir funções dentro da declaração do protótipo (`this.funcao = ...`) pode parecer mais elegante, mas será uma armadilha na maior parte dos casos, pois resulta em duplicatas como as declaradas de maneira particular (`a.funcao = ...`), só que com conteúdo idêntico, o que é totalmente desnecessário e, portanto, contra-indicado.
4. Definir funções na função construtora do protótipo (`Person.funcao = ...`) geralmente não terá utilidade; em termos de instâncias, pelo menos, com certeza não surte efeito algum.

---

## JSFiddle

Fiz um JSFiddle com uma série de testes; quem quiser dar uma olhada, [disponibilizo o link aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/ruipimentel/703o6xmu/).

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Definir instâncias no construtor equivale – mais ou menos – a criar métodos estáticos.

Comment: Excelente resposta... sempre fiquei meio sem saber direito a diferença e o terceiro caso é só amor por JS