# Classes do ES6 não permitem declaração de propriedades?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Estava experimentando com a [sintaxe de declaração de classes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108548/existe-classe-em-javascript/) do ES6/ES-2015, e não consegui declarar propriedades, somente métodos:

```
class Teste {
    constructor() {

    }

    metodo() {

    }

    // não funciona:
    //propriedade: valor

}
```

Existe alguma maneira de declarar propriedades de instância no corpo da classe? Se não existe, qual seria a justificativa para isso ter sido concebido assim?

Comment: @Renan Mas com get/set não são propriedades, são métodos acessores (é esse o termo?). Eu queria saber de propriedades "de verdade".

Answer (score 7):

Isso vai chegar, chama-se [*Public Class Fields*](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/) e está em fase 2 de desenvolvimento [nas propostas do TC39](https://github.com/tc39/proposals) (painel de programadores que sugere novas funcionalidades para a ECMAScript).

Se estiveres a usar um compilador com Babel podes usar assim:

```js
class Animal {
  familia = 'Domésticos'
  buscarNome = () => console.log(this.nome);
  buscarFamilia = () => console.log(this.familia);
  darNome(nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
  }
}

const bobby = new Animal();
bobby.darNome('bobby');
bobby.buscarNome();
bobby.buscarFamilia();
```

Answer (score 6):

Não existe provisionamento em ES6 para declaração de propriedades diretamente na classe. A razão foi a proposta de [classes maximamente mínimas](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:maximally_minimal_classes).

O ponto-chave é este:

> There is (intentionally) no direct declarative way to define either prototype data properties (other than methods), class properties, or instance property.

Que se traduz como:

> Intencionalmente, não há maneira declarativa direta de definir tanto propriedades prototípicas (à parte de métodos), propriedades de classe, ou propriedades de instância.

Propriedades devem ser declaradas fora da declaração, ou no construtor:

```js
class Teste {
  constructor() {
    this.propriedade = 'valor';
  }

  metodo() {
    console.log(this.propriedade);
  }
}

var oTeste = new Teste();
oTeste.metodo();
```

ES7, no entanto, [possui uma proposta para declaração concisa de propriedades](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/es7-property-initializers).

[Fonte.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528967/es6-class-variable-alternatives)

Comment: Obrigado, o link é bem esclarecedor! Especialmente esta frase: *Is it possible that we can come up with a class syntax that we can all agree is better than nothing, and importantly, leaves possibilities open for future enhancement?*

Comment: @bfavaretto - Não por isso! Quanto ao conteúdo, concordo: o objetivo foi apenas o de especificar a mínima estrutura funcional.