# Classes com propriedades privadas em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, classes, propriedade, ecmascript

Estou iniciando na programação *frontend*, e comecei a mexer com classes no *JavaScript* (seguindo os padrões definidos no **ECMAScript 6**). Mas estou com dificuldades no uso de propriedades e métodos privados.

Possuo no momento o seguinte código:

```
class Negociacao{

  constructor(data, quantidade, valor){

    this.data = data;

    this.quantidade = quantidade;

    this.valor = valor;

    this.volume = quantidade * valor;
  }

  getVolume(){
    return this.volume;
  }

}
```

As propriedades `data`, `quantidade`, `valor` e `volume` são públicas, mas queria torná-las privadas, e especificar seu comportamento através de `getters` e `setters`, de forma parecida com o que eu faria com o *PHP*, ou *Java*. Como poderia executar a tarefa?

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma, mas os dados, aparentemente, continuam públicos:

```
class Negociacao{
  data       = 0;
  quantidade = 0;
  valor      = 0;
  volume     = 0;
```

Neste exemplo, inclusive, os dados criados fora do construtor permanecem acessíveis, mesmo se o conteúdo do construtor for apagado, ao contrário do descrito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175173/classes-do-es6-n%C3%A3o-permitem-declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-propriedades).

E, ao utilizar `let`, como no exemplo abaixo, me aparecem os erros "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**" e "**Uncaught ReferenceError: Negociacao is not defined**":

```
class Negociacao{
  let data       = 0;
  let quantidade = 0;
  let valor      = 0;
  let volume     = 0;
```

Exemplo em *PHP* do que quero fazer:

```
class Negociacao{
  private $data;
  private $quantidade;
  private $valor;
  private $volume;

  public function __construct(Date $data, int $quantidade, float $valor){
    $this->data       = $data;
    $this->quantidade = $quantidade;
    $this->valor      = $valor;
    $this->volume     = $quantidade * $valor;
  }

  public function __get($propriedade){
    return $this->$propriedade;
  }
}
```

Comment: Arthur, existe a possibilidade de trabalhar com typescript, porém não sei se lhe atende.

Comment: Conheço o TypeScript, mas queria aprender o funcionamento com JavaScript puro. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela recomendação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoje, o que existe é uma [proposta](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) para que haja, de fato, membros privados de uma classe. [Um exemplo](https://v8.dev/features/class-fields) é a implementação na V8. E, uma vez aprovado, os membros começarão com `#`, por exemplo:

```
class Exemplo {
  #privado = 0;
  get getPrivado() {
    return this.#privado;
  }

  setPrivado(privado) {
    this.#privado = privado;
  }

  #metodoPrivado() {}
}
```

E uma dica, evite ao máximo querer programar em uma linguagem X exatamente da mesma forma que você programa numa linguagem Y. Diferentes linguagens tem padrões diferentes e formas diferentes de abordar um problema, e apesar de parecer ser uma boa ideia de início, a longo prazo é uma péssima idéia. Recomendo a leitura do [Idiomatic.js](https://github.com/rwaldron/idiomatic.js/).