# Qual a diferença entre Function e Class no React?

Tags: javascript, react

eu estou estudando React agora e eu estou com uma pequena duvida.
Qual a diferença entre os 2? Pelo o que eu vi, ambos fazem a mesma coisa.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Existe classe em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108548/existe-classe-em-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me parece que sua pergunta não é específica para o React, mas em geral da linguagem do JavaScript. De qualquer forma, vou explicar os dois casos.

**(1) No caso da linguagem própria**

Antes do [ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) (também chamado "ES6"), não existia a construção de `class` no JavaScript.

A palavra-chave class foi adicionada no ES6, permitindo você definir classes em JavaScript. Mas na verdade não se trata nada mais, nada menos de um açúcar sintático para a velha `Function`, como o exemplo abaixo demonstra:

```
class Hello {}
Hello.constructor // => ƒ Function() { [native code] }
```

**(2) No caso da biblioteca React**

Em React você pode definir um componente usando uma função ou uma classe.

**(a) componente funcional sem estado**

A maneira mais simples de definir um componente de React é usando uma função. Um componente definido dessa maneira não mantém estado ("state") nem contém métodos de ciclo de vida ("lifecycle methods"). Segue o exemplo:

```
const Botao = (props) => {
  return (
    <button type="button">{props.children}</button>
  );
};
```

Usei uma função de flexa/seta ("arrow function") acima, mas também poderia ter usado a velha `function(props) {}`. O valor retornado pela função define o modelo (visão) do componente.

**(b) componente de classe**

Outra maneira mais sofisticada de construir um componente de React é usando uma classe de ES6. Note que antes do ES6, o pessoal usava `React.createClass()` porque não havia classes. Segue um exemplo:

```
class Botao extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button type="button">{this.props.children}</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Note que um componente de classe precisa do método `render()`, que define o modelo do componente. Componentes de classe permitem que você defina um estado para armazenar informações, acessível via `this.state`. Você também pode definir componentes de ciclo de vida em componentes de classe (e.g. `componentDidMount()`). Segue um exemplo de um contador:

```
class Contador extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      contagem: 0,
    };

    this.onCounterClick = this.onCounterClick.bind(this);
  }

  onCounterClick() {
    this.setState({ contagem: this.state.contagem + 1 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button type="button" onClick={this.onCounterClick}>Contagem: {this.state.contagem}</button>
    );
  }
}
```

O exemplo acima mostra um botão cujo texto contém um contador começando do zero. Cada vez que você clica o botão, a contagem aumenta por 1.

Comment: Obrigado nbk, por ter dedicado seu tempo. Consegui compreender ambos.

Comment: Uma dúvida, o que seria este `super(props)`?

Comment: @Jota é um conceito de programação orientada a objetos. A classe `Contador` deriva da classe base ("base class") chamada `React.Component`. No construtor, quando chama `super()`, ele chama o construtor da classe base `React.Component`. É recomendado pela doc. do React que sempre execute isso se você tiver um `constructor()` definido explicitamente. Ref https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: (cont.) A razão é que se não passar `props` pro `super()`, o uso de `this.props` dentro do bloco do `constructor()` resulta em valor indefinido. É um pequeno detalhe, mas se você estiver curioso, tem essa discussão interessante em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa