# SIntaxe OOP JavaScript

Tags: javascript

venho estudando JavaScript há alguns dias e percebi que na orientação a objetos, parece conter vários formas de criar objetos e métodos. 
Exemplos:

```
class Person {
constructor (firstName) {
this.firstName= firstName
}
```

ou

```
const Person = function(firstName) {
this.firstname = firstName
}
Person.prototype.setName() {
}
```

Qual é a diferença? Há alguma maneira mais usada?

Comment: Ver https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108548/existe-classe-em-javascript

Answer (score -2):

Existem um erro no seu código, o correto seria

```
class Person {
constructor (firstName) {
this.firstName= firstName
}}
```

Dito isto, a diferença é que a segunda forma é mais antiga e mais compatível. Porém a primeira forma hoje é a forma sugerida, principalmente se você tiver um compatibilizador de versão. De qualquer modo, se você acessar o site https://caniuse.com/?search=class verá que todos os navegadores modernos já suportam classes, então a sugestão é sempre fazer da primeira forma.