# Classes em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estava pesquisando sobre criação de classes em Javascript e percebi o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var Greeter = (function () {
    function Greeter(message) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    
    Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    };
    
    return Greeter;
}());

var greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

Alguém sabe o motivo de usar uma Função autoexecutável ao invés de somente:

```js
function Greeter(message) {
    this.greeting = message;
}

Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
};
      
var greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A razão é organização e facilidade de leitura de código.

Existe uma outra possibilidade, que não está presente no teu código, que é criar "métodos privados", ie métodos que a classe pode usar internamente mas que não estão disponíveis no exterior da classe. Nesse caso ter uma [IIFE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23788/129) é util. Um exemplo poderia ser:

```js
var Greeter = (function() {
  var registados = 0;

  function magia(str) {
    return str.replace('Hello', 'Olá');
  }

  function Greeter(message) {

    this.greeting = message;
  }

  Greeter.prototype.greet = function() {
    return magia("Hello, " + this.greeting);
  };

  return Greeter;
}());

var greeter = new Greeter("Maria");
console.log(greeter.greet());
```

Costuma dizer-se *"escreve código que é fácil de apagar"*, isto porque muitas vezes o código evolui ao longo do tempo e precisamos de apagar coisas etc. Essa maneira de escrever, com **tudo o que diz respeito a essa classe encapsulado** dentro da [IIFE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23788/129) cria código organizado e é fácil ver o que está relacionado com a classe se for preciso mover essa classe para outro sitio ou "refatorar" o código.

Hoje em dia, com [classes ES6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35615/129) podemos fazer simplesmente:

```js
class Greeter {
  constructor(message) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }

  greet() {
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
  }
};

var greeter = new Greeter("world");
console.log(greeter.greet());
```

que é a maneira de organizar com sintaxe ES6.