# Modificadores de Acesso em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variáveis

#### Situação

```
function x(){
    var f = null;   // PROPRIEDADE PRIVADA DE x
    this.a = null;  // AS INSTANCIAS DE x TERÃO ACESSO A PROPRIEDADE a
    x.b = null;     // ACESSIVEL COMO x.a
}

function y(){
    x.call(this);   // HERANCA DE x
    this.c = null;
    y.d = null;
}

function z(){
    this.c = null;
    z.d = null;
}

z.prototype = x;

var t = new y;
console.log(t); // Object { a: null, c: null}
console.log(t.__proto__); // Object { constructor : y(), __proto__:Object }
                // NÃO ME EXIBE b NEM d

var p = new z;
console.log(p); // Object { c: null}
console.log(p.__proto__); // fuction x()
                // NÃO ME EXIBE b, MAS EU TENHO ACESSO p.b
```

#### Entendendo

- `x.b` na verdade esta acessando a super global `window[x][b]` e setando com `value = null`.
- `p.b` tem acesso a `b`, pois ele busca no objeto `p`, não encontrando passa para o `__proto__` que é `x`.

  ```
  console.log(typeof x) // function
  console.log(typeof x.b) // object
  ```

> Em JavaScript, quase tudo é um objeto. Todos os tipos primitivos - com exceção de null e undefined - são tratados como objetos. Eles podem receber propriedades (propriedades atribuídas de alguns tipos não são persistentes), e possuem todas as características de objetos. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos)

#### Duvidas

- O entendimento acima esta correto?
- Por que `t` não tem acesso a `t.b`, assim como `p` não tem acesso a `p.d`?
- Por que `p` não tem acesso a `p.a`, mesmo tendo como `__proto__ = x`?
- `x.b` é o mesmo que uma propriedade estatica?

Comment: @mgibsonbr, se puder ajudar, ja li muitos de suas respostas, sempre muito boas.

Comment: @bfavaretto tambem :D

Comment: você sabe que o `this`, nem sempre é o `this` que você está usando, ele varia de acordo com o escopo... ele é como um ponteiro..., outro detalhe, que você tem que considerar, é que um não enxerga o outro enquanto ele não existir.

Comment: Guilherme, você sabe que nem eu nem o gibson fomos notificados dos seus comentários acima, né? Vi por acaso. Ver http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/943

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Olá,

> O entendimento acima esta correto?

**Não.**

Acredito que antes de mais nada devemos compreender o contexto...

Ao relacionar sua dúvida com "*Modificadores de Acesso em JavaScript*" surge um ponto de reflexão, na verdade **não** existem modificadores de acesso em JavaScript, por se tratar de uma *linguagem de escopo aninhado*.
Os famosos [Closures](http://javascriptbrasil.com/2013/10/12/entenda-closures-no-javascript-com-facilidade/) (já existe uma pergunta sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript)) criam a aparência de modificadores de acesso onde você pode fazer certas funções disponíveis para objetos em determinados momentos.

> Por que t não tem acesso a t.b, assim como p não tem acesso a p.d?
>
> Por que p não tem acesso a p.a, mesmo tendo como **proto** = x?

**Entenda:**

Estes escopos aninhados baseiam-se **onde** eles foram definidos...

Então ao definir um closure com outra função, o **escopo** deste closure será **aninhado dentro** do escopo da função.

```js
function a(){
  function b(){
    }
  }
```

Isso quer dizer que o **acesso** a variáveis deve passar por uma **cadeia de escopos** até que encontre o **escopo correto** onde a variável foi definida.

Portanto, **todas** as funções que são definidas **dentro** do escopo de **outra** função, serão **sempre** closures. **Mesmo** se forem funções nomeadas.

Considerando que o escopo raiz é o escopo global de todas as funções, todas as funções estão aninhadas dentro do escopo global.

Portanto, **todas** as funções em JavaScript, são automaticamente **closures**.

```js
var x = 1;
function a(){
  x = 2; //Acesso global, logo X recebe 2
  var y = 3;
  function b(){
    y = 4; //Y aninhado dentro da função a() recebe 4
    var x = 5; //Variável local
  }
  b();
}
a();
```

Logo temos que, **X = 2** e **Y = undefined**

Posso estar enganado, mas talvez você esteja compreendendo errado o uso do [Prototype](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29864/quando-utilizar-prototype-js), que normalmente é utilizado para **simular** os **atributos** de uma **simulação** de **classe** em JavaScript.

> x.b é o mesmo que uma propriedade estatica?

Não tem como relacionar *x.b* a outra coisa se não [à](http://exame.abril.com.br/carreira/noticias/como-usar-a-crase-corretamente) um erro.

Comment: A coisa da crase é piada? Porque aí seria sem crase :P

Comment: Sim, é piada. Acredito que um toque de humor não faz mal. =D

Comment: Beleza, sou a favor do humor :) É que por escrito às vezes não fica clara a intenção

Answer (score 5):

1. O entendimento acima esta correto?
    
   **R:** x.b e var f = null, não recebem nada globalmente, pois são atributos privados da classe x, só funcionam dentro dela, como não foram usadas pra nada, elas nunca serão acessadas por nada. O mesmo vale para o y.d e o z.d. Para acessar window globalmente você teria que fazer isso fora do método `function x(){ ... }`.
2. Por que t não tem acesso a t.b, assim como p não tem acesso a p.d?
   **R:** t é instância de y, não tem acesso ao b (atributo de x) e p é instancia de z, z não tem acesso ao d (atributo de y), mesmo que y faça um call nos atributos de x, o this do call é do escopo de x, neste sentido, eles ainda pertencem ao elemento x.
3. Por que p não tem acesso a p.a, mesmo tendo como **proto** = x?
   **R:** p é instância de z, não tem como acessar a (atributo de x), mesmo que z receba uma herança no construtor de x, essa herança só herdará atributos dinâmicos (this) do objeto / classe z, e o prototipo só herdará o método x, porém nenhum atributo de x irá para dentro do escopo de p se ele não tiver um construtor. Pois ainda pertencem ao objeto x, mas o x pertence ao p agora. mas você tem acesso a p.c, pois o c é um atributo dinâmico de z. 
   Para fazer o que você quer, precisa criar um construtor da seguinte maneira:

   > **z.prototype = x;
   >
   >      z.prototype.__proto__ = z;**

   ou

   > **z.prototype = x;
   >
   >      z.prototype.constructor = z;**

   ou

   > **z.prototype = new x;**
4. x.b é o mesmo que uma propriedade estatica?
   **R:** b é um atributo estático e privado de x, não alterna no escopo dinamicamente, como o `this` o faz.

Comment: É, deu pra entender :D

Answer (score 0):

Vamos ver se consigo ajudar.

> O entendimento acima esta correto?

Sim, está correto.

> Por que t não tem acesso a t.b, assim como p não tem acesso a p.d?

Pq `x.b` é estático, e depois que vc instancia coo objeto, perde-se acesso à propriedades estáticas.

> Por que p não tem acesso a p.a, mesmo tendo como **proto** = x?

Pq a syntaxe não estava certa, tinha que ser: `z.prototype = new x;`

> x.b é o mesmo que uma propriedade estatica?

Sim, e quando vc instancia x, perde-se acesso à `x.b`.