# Função global para plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou criando um *plugin* simples com jQuery e Bootstrap, e em meu JavaScript tenho o seguinte trecho:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
   var element = this;

   var settings = $.extend({
       param1: null,
       param2: null,
       minhaLabel1: $.fn.myPlugin.defaults.translate_MINHA_LABEL_1,
       // Sequência de parâmetros
   }, options);

   // Funções de validação
   // ...

   // Eventos
   // ...

   // Funções privadas
   // ...

   // Funções Públicas
   element.clearAll = function (){
       console.debug('Elemento para ser limpo:', $(this));
       // ...
   };
   // ...

   // Start do Plugin
   // ... 

};

$fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
   translate_MINHA_LABEL_1: 'Minha Label 1',
   // ...
}
```

Ao usar o plugin tudo tem funcionado bem.

```
$('#minhaDiv').myPlugin({
   param1: 'alguma_coisa',
   param2: 'outra_coisa',
   // ...
});
```

Gosto de setar todas as traduções na página de `_Layout`, por isso criei a propriedade `defaults` em `myPlugin`, e tudo tem funcionado bem!

```
$.fn.myPlugin.defaults.translate_MINHA_LABEL_1 = '@Html.Raw(RESOURCES.LABEL_1)';
```

Agora eu gostaria de chamar a função `clearAll` para elementos que já instanciaram `myPlugin` de qualquer outro arquivo `.js`.

Imagine o seguinte trecho:

**Obs:** Insiro uma nova classe pra cada elemento que chama `myPlugin`.

```
$(".myPlugin").each(function(){
   $(this).clearAll();
});
```

Bem, nesse caso tenho um erro, como se `clearAll` não tivesse sido definido.

Então acrescentei o seguinte trecho abaixo de minha função pública `clearAll` no arquivo do `myPlugin`:

```
element.data({ clearAll: element.clearAll});
```

Agora eu posso executar a função da seguinte forma:

```
$(".myPlugin").each(function(){
   $(this).data('clearAll')();
});
```

> Mesmo tendo funcionado corretamente, achei um pouco feio. E gostaria
>   de uma abordagem como:

```
$(this).myPlugin.clearAll();
```

Tentei então fazer da forma como estou usando os resources:

```
$.fn.myPlugin.clearAll= function () {
    $(this).data('clearAll')();
};
```

Mas toda vez que chamo o trecho acima, o plugin é executado como se eu quisesse criar um novo `myPlugin`.

Comment: a variável element está privada brother...

Comment: Muito obrigado!
mas mesmo com a alteração para um contexto global, eu não consigo usar uma sintaxe mais "bonita".

Comment: Algo parecido aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100091/modificadores-de-acesso-em-javascript/101754#101754

Comment: Na parte "start do plugin", você está retornando .each(...)? Precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Pode não ser bonito como você deseja, mas uma abordagem para se trabalhar com métodos públicos seria:

```js
(function($){
$.fn.meuPlugin = function(opcoes) {
    // variáveis privadas
    var punzim = '';
    
    // métodos privados   
    var punzaum = function() {
        //...
    }
    
    // métodos públicos       
    this.flatus = function() {
        //...
        return this;
    };

    this.pum = function() {
        alert("Pum!");
    };
    
    return this.flatus();
}
})(jQuery);

var meuPlugin = $('#metano').meuPlugin();

$(".peristaltar").on("click", function(){
 meuPlugin.pum();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="metano">
  <a href="" class="peristaltar">Executar Pum</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai uma sugestão:

Encontrei uma maneira genérica de fazer isso, funciona de modo bem simples:

Na função `myPlugin` você usa o elemento puro e define uma propriedade a ele chamada "myPluggin-attached" com valor *true*:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(params) {

  // .. código

  this.get(0)['myPluggin-attached'] = true;
};
```

Já na função `clearAll` verifica se o elemento aplicado possui a propriedade definida no "myPlugin" com valor *true*:

```
$.fn.clearAll = function(param) {
    if(this.get(0)['myPluggin-attatched'] == true){
        // ..código

    }
};
```

### Demo

#### Usando o `.myPlugin` antes:

```js
var myPlugin = function(params) {
  var elementMasterValue = $(this).data('teste');
  console.log('Teste myPlugin', elementMasterValue);
  this.get(0)['myPluggin-attatched'] = true;
};

$.fn.myPlugin = myPlugin;
$.fn.clearAll = function(param) {
 if(this.get(0)['myPluggin-attatched'] == true){
    var elementValue = $(this).data('teste');
    console.log('Teste clearAll:', elementValue);
  }
};


// Instanciando plugin
$(".myPlugin").each(function() {
  $(this).myPlugin();
});

// Testando limpeza
$(".myPlugin").each(function() {
  $(this).clearAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myPlugin" data-teste="1"></div>
<div class="myPlugin" data-teste="2"></div>
```

#### Não usando o `.myPlugin` antes:

```js
var myPlugin = function(params) {
  var elementMasterValue = $(this).data('teste');
  console.log('Teste myPlugin', elementMasterValue);
  this.get(0)['myPluggin-attatched'] = true;
};

$.fn.myPlugin = myPlugin;
$.fn.clearAll = function(param) {
 if(this.get(0)['myPluggin-attatched'] == true){
    var elementValue = $(this).data('teste');
    console.log('Teste clearAll:', elementValue);
  }
};

/*
// Instanciando plugin
$(".myPlugin").each(function() {
  $(this).myPlugin();
});
*/
// Testando limpeza
$(".myPlugin").each(function() {
  $(this).clearAll(); // Nada é logado
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myPlugin" data-teste="1"></div>
<div class="myPlugin" data-teste="2"></div>
```

Comment: muito obrigado, perfeito! só tem um pequeno detalhe, dentro da função `clearAll` como consigo ter acesso a minha `div`? Pois quando uso `this`, ele me retorna a primeira função.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues, Ah, claro, erro meu. Vou corrigir e edito a resposta.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues, editado, veja se funciona.

Comment: cara, a chamada está perfeita! Muito obrigado pela ajuda com o `this` também, mas tem um probleminha... Olhe no console [desse Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jedarc/s2s9xekc/), perceba que em um contexto de vários elementos, ele guarda apenas o ultimo.

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que o `this` tem que ser passado pro contexto do `$(this)` e na função anonima não irá funcionar, terá que criar uma variavel no escopo acima.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o `this` está sendo guardado a cada execução da função `myPlugin`, como ela foi executada duas vezes, antes da `clearAll`,  ela guardou o segundo elemento e sempre executa com ele. Só penso em executar a função `myPlugin` a cada chamada do `clearAll`, para resolver isso.

Comment: Perdão eu não tinha notado o `.bind()`

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues, veja se agora funciona como esperado.

Comment: Cara, muito top e detalhado!  **Usando o .myPlugin antes**, mas no trecho  `$(this).clearAll();` não teria como usar  `$(this).myPlugin.clearAll();` ?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues, não consegui fazer dessa maneira, agora estou um pouco sem tempo, mas depois posso tentar.

Answer (score 1):

Isto seria meio que errado no contexto do elemento selecionado, pois assim:

```
$.fn.myPlugin.clearAll= function () {
    $(this).data('clearAll')();
};
```

Você **estará selecionando a função** e não o contexto do objeto, para selecionar o contexto o mais apropriado seria fazer um `return`, ficando assim:

```
$("seletor").myPlugin().clearAll();
```

Ou assim:

```
var selecioandos1 = $("seletor 1").myPlugin();
var selecioandos2 = $("seletor 2").myPlugin();

$("a.removetodos").click(function() {
     selecioandos1.clearAll();
     selecioandos2.clearAll();
});
```

A função seria:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
   var element = this;

   var settings = $.extend({
       param1: null,
       param2: null,
       minhaLabel1: $.fn.myPlugin.defaults.translate_MINHA_LABEL_1,
       // Sequência de parâmetros
   }, options);

   return {
       "clearAll": function() {
             $(element).each(function() {
                  //Ação para cada elemento selecionado
             });
        }
   }
};
```

> Todos plugins que usei usam algo parecido quando tem um método `remove`

Note também que pode ser até possível usar `.myPlugin.clearAll` sem passar o objeto, mas você vai ficar limitado ao ultimo elemento selecionado (da chamada anterior), ou seja não terá haver com a nova chamada `$("selector").`, o que pode causar várias inconsistências.

Outra sugestão que acredito ser mais limpa seria:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(type, params) {
    switch(type) {
        case "create":
            $(this).each(function() {
                var elementMasterValue = $(this).data('teste');
                console.debug('Teste myPlugin', elementMasterValue);
            });
        break;
        case "clear":
            $(this).each(function() {
                var elementMasterValue = $(this).data('teste');
                console.debug('Teste clear', elementMasterValue);
            });
        break;
    }
};

// Instanciando plugin
$(".myPlugin").myPlugin("create", {});


// Testando limpeza
$(".myPlugin").myPlugin("clear");
```

Note que coloquei o `.each` dentro da função, assim poderá usar:

```
 $(".seletor").myPlugin();
```

E:

```
 $(this).myPlugin();
```

Comment: Boa solução! Pensei em retornar o objeto mas preferi não executar novamente a função a cada chamada. Mas olhando agora, talvez não seja uma má ideia.