# Podem me explicar o que é prototype no Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Eu já vi várias explicações, mas não entendi muito bem.

Podem dar uma luz aí? Pode ser por alto mesmo.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29864/quando-utilizar-prototype-js