# O que é um prototype no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Para que serve o `prototype` no JavaScript? quando devo utiliza-lo? quais as vantagens e desvantages em não usá-lo?

Comment: Além da duplicada sugerida acima, tem também [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42962/112052) e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29864/112052)

Comment: Obrigada bb vou dar uma lida, mas o que significa isso instanciar alguma coisa?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192233/112052

Comment: Muito obrigada 